# Can't create an instance of Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService

Tags: c#, .net, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am writing my code following the instructions mentioned on this page:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started

Following this line of code from the above resource:-

```
// Create the service.
var service = new DiscoveryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
    {
        ApplicationName = "Discovery Sample",
        APIKey="[YOUR_API_KEY_HERE]",
    });
```

I have written the following code for accessing Google Calendar entries:-

```
CalendarListResource r = new CalendarListResource(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                {
                    ApiKey = "sdfsdfsdf",
                    ApplicationName = "Expenses"
                });
```

But, I am getting the following error:-

> cannot convert from
> 'Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer' to
> 'Google.Apis.Services.IClientService'

Can anyone help me resolving this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Oauth to Access Google Calendar.  The way you are doing it is for Public APIs only.

This is a quick example of getting Oauth2 to work with Google Calendar

```
/// <summary>
        /// Authenticate to Google Using Oauth2
        /// Documentation https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="clientId">From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
        /// <param name="clientSecret">From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
        /// <param name="userName">A string used to identify a user.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static CalendarService AuthenticateOauth(string clientId, string clientSecret, string userName)
        {

            string[] scopes = new string[] {
        CalendarService.Scope.Calendar  ,  // Manage your calendars
        CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly    // View your Calendars
            };

            try
            {
                // here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
                UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret }
                                                                    , scopes
                                                                    , userName
                                                                    , CancellationToken.None
                                                                    , new FileDataStore("Daimto.GoogleCalendar.Auth.Store")).Result;



                CalendarService service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Calendar API Sample",
                });
                return service;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
                return null;

            }

        }
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out. I will wait to accept this as answer, once I implement, I will accept it.

Comment: By the way, take a look in the OAuth 2.0 documentation page - https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth. You might find the information there very helpful for you.

Comment: Or this http://www.daimto.com/google-calendar-api-authentication-with-c/ there is a  sample project to go along with it